# Is Joker’s 'bat monster' an invention of the Arkham video games?

Tags: dc, batman, arkham-series, the-joker

In the Arkham series of video games, you occasionally get a view of Batman from the Joker's perspective, and you see a gargoyle-like bat monster.

I'm curious as to whether this (specifically the Joker perceiving Batman as non-human) is an invention of the Arkham games, or if it has appeared in earlier media?

[image]

Comment: It might be a reference to [Man-Bat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-Bat), a common Batman villain.

Comment: @Terriblefan I don't think so, since Man-Bat shows up in the series too. http://arkhamcity.wikia.com/wiki/Man-Bat

Comment: The more I look at the image, I'd be surprised if the designers didn't draw their inspiration from Legacy of Kain's Raziel. (Pic: http://orig03.deviantart.net/1bd5/f/2016/097/e/0/raziel_by_dekades8-d9y39ks.png)

Comment: When does this appear? As far as I can see from Google this is called the "Worst Nightmare skin", and is a batsuit/skin that was scrapped from the final game (*Arkham Origins*, that is) and is only obtainable through modding. Nothing about its appearance in Joker cutscenes.

Comment: @tobiasvl This can be quite clearly seen in the "Joker meets harly" section of the games. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9akBjJZB29w It's also visible in the ending scene https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apNhZz5EjaM

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps add those video links to your question, as well as specifying that you're talking about Arkham Origins? (I have played the Rocksteady trilogy and know that it doesn't appear there.)

Comment: @tobiasvl: [Arkham Origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Arkham_Origins) wasn’t the final game in the series. Perhaps you’re thinking of [Arkham Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Arkham_Knight).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yeah, sorry. I only mixed up the release order in my head, I'm still talking about the correct games in the comments.

Comment: @tobiasvl: *ONLY???* This is Scifi.SE son! We don’t play up in here!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I bow my head in shame!

Comment: It's a pretty common trope in Batman stories for criminals to refer to Batman as if he is a monster. So it's more than likely that similar imagery has been used in the past.